# Discord.py Ban all discord bot command

Tags: discord.py

hi I am trying to make a command in discord.py that bans all members

```
@client.command()
async def massban(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban()
        except:
            pass
```

this code does not work for some reason could anyone help?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your bot might not have permissions to see the members. Make sure that the bot has the following:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.dm_messages = True
intents.bans = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: You need to declare the intents variable first with `discord.Intents`. Please include that in your answer.